# Performance issues on complex input - alternatives to interpretation and parsed tree

Tags: c++, performance

I'm building in C++ what can be easily described as an app that graphically shows the evolution in time of a system of partial differential equation (PDE from now on).

A list of important constraints:

- The user provides the PDE system by writing them using a simplified programming code in a txt.
- The user then launches the app. As interpreting is not viable (see below), the PDE txt must be read here, but there are not heavy time limits - the user can well tolerate anything from ten seconds up to a minute of loading.
- When the app is ready, the user can and will ask it to update the system potentially hundreds of times per second, which is by far the biggest performance bottleneck in the app - imagine 10-100 intertwined PDE, with 1k - 10k spatial locations interacting with each other.
- No third-party software must be installed on the user machine. I can't ask the user to compile code or anything like that; anything more complex than editing that txt and launching the app is off chart.
- (Lesser constraint, which can be dropped) It would be cool to be able to edit the txt and reload it while the app is running through a proper UI.

As you can see, I need to parse this txt (easily done) and use its contents in the tightest (performance-wise) cycle of the app. So I can't interpret it on the fly as it would have nightmarish performance. Even if I store a parsed tree of the txt, running through the tree every iteration would still have a lot of overhead.

I know, as I saw it working, that something like this can be done with good enough performance. So how is it done? Can you dinamically create something that has similar execution time to a statically compiled function?

Any link to materials would be appreciated.

Comment: You can translate the PDE to whatever representation is convenient and fast enough to work with, from a parse tree down to machine code. If you don't want to deal with machine code, a good representation would be bytecode for a very simple virtual machine, which is easy and fast to interpret.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. can you elaborate a bit? Maybe give me some reference? I've never dealt with this kind of things, as I'm more of a UI/high level developer. Moreover, are there libraries out there that do something like this?

Comment: This is a textbook case of compiler construction, you may want to get an actual textbook on the topic such as [the Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). There are lots of bytecode compilers out there which you probably could adapt to your needs. Maybe [this thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18821475) could be of use.